# is Windows Installer Redistributable package necessary for deployment using inno setup?

Tags: .net, deployment, inno-setup

Im a .Net beginner. i need to ask something.
if i want to deploy my .net winform application (use 3.5 sp 1) using inno setup.
do i also need to deploy Windows Installer Redistributable package for each user's pc.
Is it mandatory ? thank you.

Answer (score 2):

inno setup is not Windows Installer based (see http://www.jrsoftware.org/isfaq.php#msi). So it you create a setup with respect of inno setup, you don't need Windows Installer at all.

Comment: @leie, please mark this one as answer. Or next time nobody answers your questions.